# Filter module CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp

Probably this is not the smartest question. But I'm quite new to CakePHP and the MVC model. Now, creating a simple website with connection to a database is quite easy. But I need to expand the website with a Filter module, like on http://www.femme.nl/badmode, left sidebar. But how to do that? I can't create a Model for that, cause CakePHP complains "Filter" is not a table in the database. So is it better to create a plugin, or behavior.... I don't get it anymore. I got a script already, but don't know a good way to implement it.

I need the model in multiple views, and thus Controllers, so that's the reason I got stuck.

Comment: You might want to leverage https://github.com/cakedc/search

Comment: Thank you for your input Mark, I'll look definitely at the search plugin. But my question is actually what to do with such modules. Or it's better to create a component or Model, View and Controller. Cause it's not connected to a single table, it doesn't even contain a table, it just searches all tables in the database and returns an array with possibilities. That's why it looks so complicated to me. And because of the rule "keep controllers thin and models fat", I'm not doing it right by creating a component.

Comment: Then you might want to take a look at https://github.com/kvz/cakephp-elasticsearch-plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to search all tables in the database, according to your second comment you've made to your questions, then you want a search index. A search index can be build by yourself using your database (guess mysql) and using fulltext search.

A better solution would be to use dedicated search index database solution like Elastic Search or Sphinx for that purpose.

But Mark is still right: You want to use the PRG pattern, which the search plugin implements, to transform the POST of the form in your sidebar into conditions that can be used for the search query.

Comment: Alright then. Thank you for your help. I'll use the search plugin what you and Mark advised me to do. It does seem like it will become quite easier to create a filter that way... So we'll see :)

Comment: Delayed comment, but it works :) See http://wearus.com/tr/ and choose a menu item (not the first, that's the homepage link). At the moment I'm looking for a way to combine it with elastic search. To make the search engine more user-friendly and faster.